# conditional mysql operation in shell script

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, unix

I have the following shell script which writes volumes in a `find` command to a file, and loads that file into a mysql database:

```
# find all the paths and print them to a file
sudo find $FULFILLMENT/ > $FILE
sudo find $ARCH1/ >> $FILE
sudo find $ARCH2/ >> $FILE
sudo find $MASTERING/ >> $FILE

# load the file into the mysql database, `files`, table `path`
/usr/local/bin/mysql -u root files -e "TRUNCATE path"
/usr/local/bin/mysql -u root files -e "LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/files.txt' INTO TABLE path"
```

`TRUNCATE` is to be used to delete all the old entries before adding the new. However, if **any** of the `find` commands don't work (for example, if the volume isn't accessible), I want it to skip on the two `mysql` commands. How would I modify the above script to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will execute your two `mysql` commands only if all the `find` commands succeed:

```
# find all the paths and print them to a file
sudo find $FULFILLMENT/ > $FILE &&
sudo find $ARCH1/ >> $FILE &&
sudo find $ARCH2/ >> $FILE &&
sudo find $MASTERING/ >> $FILE &&
{
  # load the file into the mysql database, `files`, table `path`
  /usr/local/bin/mysql -u root files -e "TRUNCATE path"
  /usr/local/bin/mysql -u root files -e "LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/files.txt' INTO TABLE path"
}
```

The `&&` operator causes the command on the RHS to run only if the command on the LHS succeeds. The `{ ... }` groups the two `mysql` commands into one compound command, so either both run (if the last `find` succeeds) or neither does (if the last `find` does not succeed).

You can use this if there is more to your script that should run whether or not the `find`s succeed and the `mysql` commands run.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
sudo find $FULFILLMENT > $FILE || exit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `#!/bin/bash -e` or add a line with `set -e` above the find commands. That way, Bash will automatically abort as soon as a command fails. It's good practice to always do this by default, since you rarely want to continue when the previous command fails:

```
set -e

# find all the paths and print them to a file
sudo find $FULFILLMENT/ > $FILE
sudo find $ARCH1/ >> $FILE
sudo find $ARCH2/ >> $FILE
sudo find $MASTERING/ >> $FILE

# load the file into the mysql database, `files`, table `path`
/usr/local/bin/mysql -u root files -e "TRUNCATE path"
/usr/local/bin/mysql -u root files -e "LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/files.txt' INTO TABLE path"
```

Comment: Could you please show a full line of code example of using this?

Comment: Uhm, `set -e` is a full line of code example, but I added it in context in your script.